# Flume 1.4 with Hadoop 2.2.0 and hdfs sink type having issue

Tags: hadoop, flume

Below mentioned is my flume configuration file...

```
# example.conf: A single-node Flume configuration

# Name the components on this agent
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# reading file using tail command and sending data to channel
a1.sources.r1.type = spooldir
a1.sources.r1.spoolDir = /data/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/logs
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1

a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs://PPWFMD509:9160/flume-test
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = events-
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.round = true
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundValue = 10
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundUnit = minute
```

running on hadoop version 2.2.0 (have added hadoop-core 1.2.1.jar file to the flume lib directory)

on the maven repository i am not able to file jar for hadoop-core2.2.x. why ? and what id hadoop-core-0.20 versions ?

when running the same and placing file have below mentioned exception

```
2014-02-26 14:51:30,865 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.open(BucketWriter.java:219)] Creating hdfs://PPWFMD509:9160/flume-test/events-.1393406490812.tmp
2014-02-26 14:51:31,079 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [WARN - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:418)] HDFS IO error
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
```

Answer (score 0):

The message `Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4` points that you faced a compatibility issue. Flume is trying to use hadoop client version which is not compatible with your hadoop cluster (1.2.1 cannot work with 2+ version).

As for lib version, this is quote from [Hadoop Releases](http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html):

```
1.2.X - current stable version, 1.2 release
2.5.X - current stable 2.x version
0.23.X - similar to 2.X.X but missing NN HA.
```